# Grails Spring security facebook plugin sample FacebookAuthDAOImpl

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security, facebook-oauth

I started looking at [this plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook) for facebook integration in grails 2.0 apps. I ran through he setup instructions listed and got a sample app working....for the most part.

I'm having problems fleshing out `FacebookAuthDaoImpl` which implements the interface `FacebookAuthDao`. Now I know this class is supposed to be configured to match the apps domain structure, but for a sample app with no out-of-the-ordinary domain settings what would be an appropraite implementation of this interface?

What I'm trying to achieve is when a facebook user is created, a spring security user should also be created and they both be associated.

Edit:

After running `s2-init-facebook` and getting the generated `FacebookAuthDaoImpl`. 
I executed `run-app` and then I get an error roles in `getRoles()` of the generated impl.

```
No such property: roles for class: com.gotomanners.auth.FacebookUser
```

I fixed this by adding

```
roles = [new GrantedAuthorityImpl('ROLE_USER'), new GrantedAuthorityImpl('ROLE_FACEBOOK')]
```

The app starts fine now and I can click the fbConnect button which connects to facebook fine but on returning to the app there is no facebookUser or regular user in the DB .... which is why I went on to look at using `createAppUser()` from `DefaultConnectedFacebookAuthDaoImpl`

Comment: Default (auto-generated) implementation must be enough for simple webapp. Do you have any problems with default implementation?

Comment: the autogenerated impl doesn't create a Spring security user that is linked to the created Facebook user. Looking through the source, there's a method `createAppUser(token)` which isn't implemented

Comment: Hm, where you've found `createAppUser(token)`? maybe `create(token)`?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I was poking through the plugin source and in the `DefaultConnctedFacebookAuthDao` exists that method createAppUser(token). What i'm trying to achieve is when a facebook user is created, a spring security user should also be created and they both be associated. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Oh, I got it. `DefaultConnctedFacebookAuthDao` isn't finished yet. Did you executed `s2-init-facebook`? It must generate an default dao implementation for you, at `src/groovy`

Comment: Yes i had previously run `s2-init-facebook`... please see my edit above for more info

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6145/discussion-between-gotomanners-and-splix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook) has since been updated(`0.6.2` at this time of writing) and this issue is now resolved!